# Copied Excel Files losing Web query

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm using `Python` and the module `openpyxl`.

I have been able to:

```
    CreateFile = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename= 'OldWorkbook.xlsm', keep_vba = True)
    Sheet = CreateFile.active
    Sheet['A1']=("What Ever You Want")
    CreateFile.save('NewWorkbook.xlsm')
```

But when I open the `NewWorkbook` the web query I defined in `OldWorkbook` is not there in `NewWorkbook`, any suggestions?

Comment: Is it not there, or is it not functioning? Can you look inside?

Comment: the cell range is defined as it was in the original file but in the new file it doesn't give me the option to edit the query when I highlight it, so my best guess is that it isn't there.

Comment: I shouldn't have said I guess because it is definitely not there.

Comment: To confirm that it's "definitely not there", check in `Data -> Connections` (see the section **edit an existing Web query** [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-external-data-from-a-Web-page-708f2249-9569-4ff9-a8a4-7ee5f1b1cfba#bmcreate_a_web_query))

Comment: Ok, I just checked it out and it is definitely not there

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a web query is but I suspect it is something that is not (yet) supported by openpyxl and thus lost when working on the file. Because of the structure of the file format, files are completely rewritten when they are edited.

You can submit a bug issue requesting the feature but providing a pull request is the best way to get it.